# How to multiple 2 columns using [nested for loop] in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This is really driving me nuts. Say I have 3 dataset I am combining into a dataframe.

```
    a = c(1,2,3,4)
    b = c(2,4,6,8)
    c = c(3,6,9,12)

    d = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c)) # combined dataframe
```

I could just write:

```
    multiply = d[,1]*d[,2]*d[,3]
    #[1]   6  48 162 384
```

But this is not feasible in case I have many columns, so I need nested  for- loop statement, so this is what I attempt:

```
   for (col in 1:ncol(d)){
    for (j in 1:ncol(d)){
   multiply=0
   multiply = d[,col]*d[,j]
    }
  }
  print(multiply)
  #[1]   9  36  81 144
```

It just took the column 2 and multiple with column 3. WHY???? Any improvement of my **nested for-loop**will be highly appreciated, this is what i am interested to know more about.

Please do not suggest a solution which involves using apply functions. I am already aware of them.

Comment: Because I want to understand how the for loop works. I am obviously doing something wrong since I am not getting the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Reduce`

```
 Reduce(`*`, d)
 #[1]   6  48 162 384
```

---

Or with `rowProds` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowProds(as.matrix(d))
#[1]   6  48 162 384
```

---

If we need a `for` loop

```
v1 <- rep(1, nrow(d))
for(j in seq_along(d)){
  v1 <- v1*d[,j]
 }
v1
#[1]   6  48 162 384
```

Comment: Can you improve the for loop statement in my question. That will help me to understand better. Thanks

Comment: @BoroDega The above solutions should work with as many columns you have.  Why do you need a `for` loop?

Comment: I really want to understand the logic behind the nested for loop statement in r and how it works.

Comment: @BoroDega I updated with a `for` loop, but not a `nested for` loop.  Hope it helps

Comment: if I understood your for loop. You created a new variable called v1 containing only 1s have the same row number as dataframe d. Then you mulitple v1 with the dataframe d.

Comment: @BoroDega Yes, that is right.  and updated `v1` on each loop so that it gets updated with the new value before it multiplies the next column.

Comment: @BoroDega Is this answer still not optimal for you?

Comment: I still have not figured out why my for-loop statement is not working and what is it I am doing wrong. I appreciate your answers, but I cannot understand why my for loop takes the 2nd column and multiple it with the 3rd rather than looping through column 1 multiply it with column 2 and so on..Hope someone will give me a dummy explanation:)

Comment: @BoroDega What you are doing is multiplying each column value with combination of the column values in the dataset.  The `for` loop prints the last set of output values.  If you want to check, try `lapply(seq_along(d), function(i) lapply(seq_along(d), function(j) d[,i]* d[,j]))`.  Note that in each loop `multiply` is assigned to 0.  So, the last value is `9 36 81 144`

Comment: what would be the remedy. What should I do in my above for-loop statement? Should I declare a new variable? Should I state for (j in 2:ncol(d)?

Comment: @BoroDega The remedy is already showed in my post.  If you are doing a unnecessary nested loop, not using that nested loop is the remedy.  End of story.  It is unnecessary because your result doesn't require nesting..